# Add custom content to a wordpress theme template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm in the process of customising a theme (styling, css, etc). However, I ran into a small problem, basically I wan't to include an introductory message at the top of the home/index template, and then have it as an option(text area) in the theme options panel. How do I go about doing this. Sorry for the noobish question, haven't found any straightforward solution yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a significant customization that will require changes to the PHP code for the theme. You need a PHP programmer, preferably one who knows WordPress.

Comment: I agee with Mike on this one. You would need to add a theme location for insertion, create a theme option menu, add functions for that and hook it up in your theme.
If it's not to be changed frequently maybe you could hardcode it?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about hardcoding it, but I'm not really comfortable with the idea since its being delivered to a client. I can brave dabbling in php, if I'm pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @Emmanuel I'll have something for you in about 4 or 6 hours, when I get the time.